# Rails better_errors gem server not starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, better-errors-gem

Since I isntalled better_errors gem I can't start my server using command rails server. I have tried adding lines into my development.rb like `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! "0.0.0.0/0"` or `BetterErrors::Middleware.allow_ip! ENV['TRUSTED_IP'] if ENV['TRUSTED_IP']` but it didn't work.
This is my error message when I try to start server:

```
/home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:6:in `caller_locations': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:6:in `set_backtrace'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/exception_extension.rb:15:in `call'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/exception_extension.rb:15:in `block in <class:Exception>'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:10:in `set_backtrace'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/exception_extension.rb:15:in `call'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/exception_extension.rb:15:in `block in <class:Exception>'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/exception_extension.rb:10:in `set_backtrace'
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/web_console/exception_extension.rb:15:in `call'
 ... 5885 levels...
from /home/jakub/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

And my gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                                '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                                       '3.1.7'
gem "paperclip",
git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'faker',                                        '1.4.2'
gem 'will_paginate',                        '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',  '0.0.10'
gem 'sass-rails',                           '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                             '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',                         '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',                         '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',                           '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                             '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [active issue](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/243) on github since 2014. One workaround seems to be to move `gem 'better_errors'` out of the `development` and `testing` groups from your Gemfile.

You can also start to restart `spring` manually which might resolve your problem:

```
cd /your/project
spring stop
...
spring start
...
```

In your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem "paperclip",
git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'

group :development, :test do
  # ...
end
```

Other things you could try:

- Remove your `Gemfile.lock`, keep your Gemfile as is and rerun bundle install. Make sure `rails s` is not run while doing that.
- Remove `better_errors` version from you Gemfile

Comment: Yeah, I deleted better_errors from my gemfile and now server works, is there any possibility to make server work with this gem?

Comment: Yes, you can simply place it below the other gems, not using the gem `groups`. If you are still in development, and don't serve your app in production yet, this is a reasonable thing to do.